# TeraTerm execution through the Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-prompt, teraterm

I have some basic simple two character commands to be executed in TeraTerm.

Is there a way to execute the same TeraTerm commands through a Windows command prompt? This will overcome my dependency to open TeraTerm and then running, commands. I can directly write some .bat file to execute my short commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your commands are for teraterm, and not for the OS of your device connected via teraterm, you can save your commands into a .ttl file (using notepad or whatever). You can still make it work if the commands are for the OS (using a command line or whatever in the shell of the OS program connected), but you will have to make extra commands to navigate to it.

Using the .ttl file, you can make a .bat file that does two things:

```
cd C:\Program Files\teraterm
TTPMacro C:\[point to .ttl file]
```

This won't prevent teraterm from opening, because if you script involves you interfacing with teraterm at all, it'll open unless you add **/V** after TTPMcro. However, it will be a hands free experience.

You can find out more about deploying the macro here: https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/macro/

And a list of all the commands here: https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/macro/command/index.html

And if you need special characters for navigation (ctrl+s, etc), the ASCII code table is here: https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/macro/appendixes/ascii.html

Hope that helps!

---

If it's only several basic commands, you can make it without the ttl file by using TTermPro in lieu of TTPMacro.

```
cd C:\Program Files\teraterm
TTERMPRO /C=1 (connect thru serial com 1)
TTERMPRO etc etc
```

The syntax for command line using TTERMPRO can be found here: https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/commandline/teraterm.html

Comment: @J.Deo, Thank you for a valuable reply. My commands are only for activating device through tera-term, mostly the commands will 'ON', 'OFF'...

Comment: If it's very simple, you can try using TTERMPRO as well, I have updated the answer to include some of that information. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to get Teraterm to close after this?  It stays connected and I can't send another command.

Comment: @Sanjo - See [this](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/4/en/macro/command/closett.html)